# create columns from transaction type in table

Tags: sql

I have an SQL query that groups by transaction type and then sums amount, but would like the summed amount to be in a column for each transaction type

i have this:

```
select Job, 
       sum(amount) as Amount, 
       transaction_type 
 from JCT_CURRENT__TRANSACTION
WHERE transaction_date >= {?Start Date} 
  and transaction_date <= {?End Date}
GROUP BY Job, transaction_type
ORDER BY Job ASC
```

But would like:

```
Job  | TransType1AmountSum  | TransType2AmountSum  |  TransType3AmountSum
```

so i would only have one line per job.

Comment: What Db Engine are you using? MSSQL / Oracle etc?

Comment: @lukemh - since you are using SQL Server, you could also look at the PIVOT operator - Refer http://sqlserver-qa.net/blogs/t-sql/archive/2008/08/27/4809.aspx for an example.

Comment: @Hogan Transaction Type is not an index.

Comment: @lukemh : might still be faster -- if you have N rows mine is 3O(N) -- that is three scans of the trans type.  While the 3 if statements have to do O(3N), that is 3 if statements in each row.  It all depends on which constants are faster, scans or CASE.  In general SQL is faster at scanning than at branching.  Add an index and scanning is instant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
  SELECT t.job,
         SUM(CASE WHEN t.transaction_type = 'TransType1' THEN t.amount ELSE NULL END) AS TransType1AmountSum,
         SUM(CASE WHEN t.transaction_type = 'TransType2' THEN t.amount ELSE NULL END) AS TransType2AmountSum,
         SUM(CASE WHEN t.transaction_type = 'TransType3' THEN t.amount ELSE NULL END) AS TransType3AmountSum
    FROM JCT_CURRENT_TRANSACTION t
   WHERE transaction_date BETWEEN {?Start Date} 
                              AND {?End Date}
GROUP BY t.job
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select Job, 
       sum(IF(transaction_type = 'transtype1', amount, 0)) as TransType1AmountSum, 
       ...,
       transaction_type 
 from JCT_CURRENT__TRANSACTION
WHERE transaction_date >= {?Start Date} 
  and transaction_date <= {?End Date}
GROUP BY Job
```

Comment: Won't this get an error since transaction_type is not in the group by list?

Comment: oops, i thought it is mysql, sorry.

Comment: @lukemh: because i've written it thinking you're working with mysql

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do it that should be faster (esp if you have an index on transaction type and are doing more than one operation -- like avg and count.)

This is in TSQL

```
SELECT Job.Job, 
       sum(T1.amount) as TransType1AmountSum, count(T1.amount) as Count1, avg(T1.amount) as Avg1
       sum(T2.amount) as TransType2AmountSum, count(T2.amount) as Count2, avg(T2.amount) as Avg2
       sum(T3.amount) as TransType3AmountSum, count(T3.amount) as Count3, avg(T3.amount) as Avg3
 FROM JCT_CURRENT__TRANSACTION AS Job
 JOIN JCT_CURRENT__TRANSACTION T1 ON Job.Job = T1.Job AND T1.TransactionType = 'TransType1'
 JOIN JCT_CURRENT__TRANSACTION T2 ON Job.Job = T2.Job AND T2.TransactionType = 'TransType2'
 JOIN JCT_CURRENT__TRANSACTION T3 ON Job.Job = T3.Job AND T3.TransactionType = 'TransType3'
WHERE Job.transaction_date >= {?Start Date} 
  and Job.transaction_date <= {?End Date}
GROUP BY Job.Job
```